# replace electric panel

Tags: electrical

I would like to replace an ite pushmatic panel with the square d type QO panel. The neutral bar or plate in the pushmatic panel is above the main breaker. The neutral bars in the square QO are at the sides. Rather then splice all the neutrals and grounds so they are long enough to reach the sides of the QO panel, I want to remove the bars from the sides of the QO panel and remount them horizontal in the area above the main breaker in the QO panel. They will both be bounded to the panel thru their mounting screws. Where the service entrance  neutral is terminated in the QO panel ,I can ,right next to it on the same bus ,mount another terminal. From that terminal I can install, the right size conductor to each of the remounted bars. Does this sound okay?

Comment: Is this a main panel or a subpanel that you are replacing?

Comment: This is a Main panel

Comment: Can you mount the new panel a bit higher on the wall than the old one?

Comment: Also, what wiring method was used for the branch circuit conductors entering the panel?

Comment: i could mount the panel, may 2 inches higher. The panel that exists is only about 4 inches below the floor joists. , I'm not sure there would be enough room to get my hands in that space to feed the wires through the connectors. Its possible though.      I'm not sure what you mean by the question, what wiring method? The wires were run thru wire clamps. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I mean -- are the branch circuits (and feeders) coming into the panel wired using NM (aka Romex)? Some sort of armored cable? Conduit?

Comment: they are Romex.  They are mostly 12-2 wg, approx. 12 of those. Approx. 2 14-2 wg and there are 3  10-3 wg. And I believe there is at least 1 10-2 wg

Comment: Are accessory ground bars sold for the panel you are installing?  Do any of them mount near the top?  Since this is a main panel, it is not illegal to land neutrals and grounds on the same bar.   (by the way, **this** is why I don't like "neat panels with groomed wires" - you need to leave enough slack for things to change, *not least*, getting the neutral down to the GFCI/AFCI breaker.)

Comment: I will have to check to see if there are accessory ground bars sold.  I understand what you mean by leaving room for change. I like cutting the wire the length of the panel or box and then neatly tuck the excess some where.  I need to go to Menards and look inside the panel I'm interested in. Maybe those side bars can be flipped up with one end yet fastened.  Thanks for your time and support. I had moving those bars in mind but with doubts. I needed to listen to someone besides me.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of complex impossible/impasse problem you get when you buy from big-box.  Now a proper vendor, i.e. an **electrical supply house**, knows his products like no other, knows the tricks, and if there's a panel that'll put the neutrals/grounds up high, he'll know which one.  Talk to them.  As for the matter of price, that's a big joke. Big-box lowballs a few items they think you'll check, and gouges you on everything else. 3/4 EMT couplers: Menards: $2/3 supply: $4/20.  120mm boxes: Menards: $5 supply $2.  Build a relationship with those guys.

Comment: @Harper -- QOs definitely have accessory ground bars, but it seems that there are no mounting spaces for them at the top of the backpan?!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah, that's why you ask the electrical supply, they'll know which other panels will.  I assume OP isn't married to QO.